# Error: Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

Any idea why I am getting this error? It comes up after running through and accepting the l and r values. I do not get any errors when I compile, just when I run it. This is just the first half of my program. However, I do not want to proceed with this error hanging around.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main()
{
    int y, n, q, v, w;
    double a, b, c, d, e, l, r;
    printf("Enter lower bound l:");
    scanf("%d, &l");
    printf("Enter upper bound r:");
    scanf("%d, &r");
    printf("The coefficients should be entered to match this form: ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e ");
    printf("Enter value of a:");
    scanf("%d, &a");
    printf("Enter value of b:");
    scanf("%d, &b");
    printf("Enter value of c:");
    scanf("%d, &c");
    printf("Enter value of d:");
    scanf("%d, &d");
    printf("Enter value of e:");
    scanf("%d, &e");
    //initializing the sign counters to zero
    q = 0;
    w = 0;
    //here we will count the lower bound sign variations with q holding the count 
    //I'm going to compare each term with the absolute value of it to check the sign
    //then I will see if they are the same or equal and increment the count as necessary

    if (a == abs(a))
    {
        y = 1;
    }
    else 
    {
        y = 0;
    }
        if ((a*4*l + b) == abs(a*4*l + b))
    {
        n = 1;
    }
    else 
    {
        n = 0;
    }
//if they are different signs then one is added to the count
if (y != n) 
{
    q++;
}
    if ((6*a*l*l + 3*b*l + c) == abs(6*a*l*l + 3*b*l + c))
    {
        y = 1;
    }
    else 
    {
        y = 0;
    }
    if (y != n) 
{
    q++;
}
if ((4*a*l*l*l + 3*b*l*l + 2*c*l + d) == abs(4*a*l*l*l + 3*b*l*l + 2*c*l + d))
    {
        n = 1;
    }
    else 
    {
        n = 0;
    }
    if (y != n) 
{
    q++;
}
    if ((a*l*l*l*l + b*l*l*l + c*l*l + d*l + e) == abs(a*l*l*l*l + b*l*l*l + c*l*l + d*l + e))
    {
        y = 1;
    }
    else 
    {
        y = 0;
    }
    if (y != n) 
{
    q++;
}

//now for the upper bounds sign changes
if (a == abs(a))
    {
        y = 1;
    }
    else 
    {
        y = 0;
    }
        if ((a*4*r + b) == abs(a*4*r + b))
    {
        n = 1;
    }
    else 
    {
        n = 0;
    }
//if they are different signs then one is added to the count
if (y != n) 
{
    w++;
}
    if ((6*a*r*r + 3*b*r + c) == abs(6*a*r*r + 3*b*r + c))
    {
        y = 1;
    }
    else 
    {
        y = 0;
    }
    if (y != n) 
{
    w++;
}
if ((4*a*r*r*r + 3*b*r*r + 2*c*r + d) == abs(4*a*r*r*r + 3*b*r*r + 2*c*r + d))
    {
        n = 1;
    }
    else 
    {
        n = 0;
    }
    if (y != n) 
{
    w++;
}
    if ((a*r*r*r*r + b*r*r*r + c*r*r + d*r + e) == abs(a*r*r*r*r + b*r*r*r + c*r*r + d*r + e))
    {
        y = 1;
    }
    else 
    {
        y = 0;
    }
    if (y != n) 
{
    w++;
}   
//now I have the number of sign changes when both bounds are put in
//the lower bound value is held in q
//the upper bound value is held in w
//the absolute value of q-w is the number of roots this will be held in v
v = abs(q-w);

if (v = 0)
{
    printf("The polynomial has no roots in the given interval.");
    return 0;
}



}
```

Comment: A segmentation fault is a runtime error. It indicates the wrong use of pointers (wrong memory addressing). Please attach the stack trace.

Comment: `gcc -Wall -Werror -g main.c && gdb ./a.out`, type `r` and press enter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
scanf("%d, &l");
```

to

```
scanf("%d", &l);
```

and do the same for the rest of the `scanf`s. Also,change

```
if (v = 0)
```

to

```
if (v == 0)
```

And the correct format specifier for a `double` is `%lf`. Also,change

```
main()
```

to

```
int main(void)
```

and move

```
return 0;
```

at the end of `main`.

Comment: And with the error being that simple, I think I have been staring at this screen for too long and need some sleep. Thank you sir.

Comment: @Downvoter, Is there something wrong in this answer?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `"%f"` as the format specifier when receiving floating point types.

Otherwise the program behaviour is undefined.

Although not the cause of any runtime crashes, you're on dangerous ground comparing `==` on floating point types that are the result of a polynomial calculation. You're *probably* fine in this particular instance, but do take care.